# Logic App Response action to return status code reason

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When a Logic App uses the *Request* trigger to receive inbound requests and the *Response* built-in action to send the response back to the caller, the *Response* action must include the Status Code - 200, 400, 401, etc.

Along with the Status Code, I'd like to be able to send the reason of the status code, in the same way it can be done in the API Management by using the [set-status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-status-policy#policy-statement) policy.

Is it possible at all to specify the status code **reason** in the Logic App [Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres?tabs=consumption#add-a-response-action) action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible at all to specify the status code  **reason**  in the Logic App  [Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres?tabs=consumption#add-a-response-action)  action?

No it is not possible using Logic Apps.

But if its business need, as an alternative, You can define it in the response body at your client application and you need to pass the response body as a reason.

You can submit a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/cb47c115-7926-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) in more detail.

Comment: Just as I thought, thanks. I cannot change the schema of the response, so I'll have to resort to setting the status code reason in the API Management.